# Go back to the previous state

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying various solutions from Google but all of them seems to be for Ionic 1 and other versions of Ionic and Angular.

**HTML**

```
<button class="edit" (click)="goBackToEnhancementPage();">Edit</button>
```

On button click I want to goto to the previous state in the history

**TypeScript**

This is the current state

```
 export class BookingConfirmationPage {

      //Some properties

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams ) {
        //Some codes
      }

      goBackToEnhancementPage(){
        canGoBack();
      }

    }
```

**Previous State**

```
export class BookingEnhancementPage {

  //Some code 

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder ) {
    //This is previous state
  }

}
```

This doesn't work. Please advise what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is your previous state? update the post with more information.!

Comment: @Aravind please check I have edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing from your question you are trying to use navController to go back to your previous state, aka "back" function.

The way ionic navigation works is like a stack, new pages will be pushed to the top of the stack via "push" via pages will be removed from the top of the stack via "pop"

To go back to your previous state, u can use :

```
this.navCtrl.pop();
```

But before that make sure you have push your previous page into navController or you have setRoot your "BookingConfirmationPage" page.

You might want to read up on : https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/

If you want your previous details in BookingEnhancementPage to be filled with your user's previously entered data, you might want to use a combination of localstorage and onPageBeforeEnter/onPageWillEnter to populate the fields.